# Is there any command in the terminal to find the path to Python in virtualenv?

Tags: python, django, eclipse, macos, virtualenv

I'm trying to use virtualenv within Eclipse/PyDev but for that I need to know where the interpreter is. I'm on a Mac OSX 10.8.5. Is there any command in the terminal I can use to find the path to python and all the libraries/modules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you create a virtualenv ?

```
virtualenv <your_env>
```

This will create a new folder containing the interpreter, the librairies, etc.

If you did, the python executable is at `<your_env>/bin/python` and the libs are in `<your_env>/lib`.

If you did activate it (using `source <your_env>/bin/activate`) and you don't remember where the folder is, simply use :

```
which python
```

And it will tell you which python executable is used.

Comment: Thank you! I did activate it.

Answer (score 1):

If the virtualenv is active, then...

```
which python
```

Should give you the path.